# Empty space showing in Title when showing a page as wordpress home

Tags: wordpress

I have a page created and its title is empty. When I choose that page shown as the homepage, the title is like this " - TechNeg" where the space behind that dash is my page's empty title. How do I resolve this?

Comment: website url : https://techneg.co.in

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have has support for title tag [add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_theme_support/).

Also, make sure you set Site Title from WordPress dashboard -> settings -> general -> Site Title

[image: Secrrenshot]

Hope that helps!

Comment: What I meant was I've set Wordpress to display a static Page as my homepage which is a page I built with page builder and it has no title. Also, the Title in General > site title is set. But I don't know for whatever reason it's ending up showing titles of both my Site as well as that static page (static page has no title that's why there is an empty space followed by a dash but when set a title in my page, it repeats like "TechNeg - TechNeg" where the first one is page's title and the second one is my site's title. How do I resolve this?